# What is the best way to pass a JSON array multiple times using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, json, django, post

Super confused about this one. I have a website that asks the user to enter the courses they took in highschool, and based on that it retrieves a list of eligible careers from the database as JSON data. Later, the user selects their personality type, and that list of careers is supposed to be filtered further more in the backend to get the new eligible careers.

Retrieving list of careers the first time based on courses:

```
    if(form.$valid) {

            $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'https://some-django-url/get-careers-first-round/',
              data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in courses
              headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  
             })
            .success(function(data){
              $scope.careers = $scope.$eval( careers );
            }); 
        }
```

Sending list of careers again to the backend (Django) to do extra filtering. I am stuck here. I attempted to do the following:

```
$http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'https://some-django-url/ajax/get-careers-second-round/',
              data    : $.param($scope.careers),  // ???
              headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } 
             })
            .success(function(data){     
              $scope.careers = $scope.$eval( data.careers );            
            });
```

But this is not sending the careers list properly. What's wrong with my code? And is that the recommended way to pass a previously retrieved array back to the backend?? (considering I am using Django as a backend framework) ?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: Can you check the value of `$scope.careers ` before you make the second call?

Another solution you can do is pass the courses, again, and their personalities in the second call and the backend will take care of getting the careers again and filtering them based on personalities. This will repeat the process of getting careers though.

Comment: The first time $scope.careers prints out a perfect JSON Array. The second time it prints out weird stuff with +'s and = signs between words. Also thanks for the suggestion! It's a good idea